# How to remove specific key value from array of dictionary from User Defaults swift3

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsdictionary, nsuserdefaults

I have an array of dictionary saved in User Defaults. I am showing these value in UITableview. When the user right swipes the table cell and remove it, the cell is successfully deleted, but it is not actually deleted from User Defaults.Here what I tried :

```
   var notificationArray: [[String: AnyObject]] = []
   var title = [String]()
   var detail = [String]()

   override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
      if let tempArray = UserDefaults().array(forKey: "notificationArray") as? [[String: AnyObject]] {

        notificationArray = tempArray

         self.title = tempArray.flatMap { $0["title"] as? String }
         self.detail = tempArray.flatMap { $0["detail"] as? String }
    }
  }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        print("Deleted")

        self.title.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        self.detail.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)

       notificationArray.append(["title": title as AnyObject, "detail": detail as AnyObject]) 
       UserDefaults.standard.set(notificationArray, forKey: "notificationArray")       
          print("title, detail", title, detail)       
    }
}

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return title.count
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
    {
       return 80
     }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
       return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell : SubCategoryTableViewCell =   tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! SubCategoryTableViewCell


        cell.notificationTittleLabel.text = title[indexPath.row]
        cell.notificationDetailLabel.text = detail[indexPath.row]

        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: You are appending a new dictionary to `notificationArray` instead of removing the required element.

Comment: I already tried this one :-  var myNotificationArray = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "notificationArray") as? [AnyHashable]
            myNotificationArray?.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(myNotificationArray, forKey: "notificationArray")
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize(), but it doesn't work.

Comment: All you need is `notificationArray.remove(at:indexPath.row)` and the save it back to user defaults.

Answer (score 0):

This is worked for me. Thanks, @Paulw11 :)

```
  var myNotificationArray = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "notificationArray") as? [AnyHashable]
  myNotificationArray?.remove(at: indexPath.row) 
  UserDefaults.standard.set(myNotificationArray, forKey: "notificationArray") 
  UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```